# Image sharing intent for latest Api in android studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-sharing

My question is I am now trying to add "Share this image" button for my Android App but I can't share it.All my images are found in Drawables folder.I tried so many codes here in stack and android developer codes but it all went empty.My main struggle is getting or referring the Uri for the images.Can anyone help me with this???

What is the latest code to refer UriToImage??

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");`enter code here`
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,   getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Comment: what is the value of `uriToImage` ?

Comment: Uri  uriToImage = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.afcethiopia.test/drawables/a1.jpeg");

Comment: try removing the extension & use this `Uri uriToImage = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.afcethiopia.test/drawable/a1");`

Comment: When I share the image in viber and other apps it doesn't load.It shows empty box....I think there still is a problem with the uriToImage reference..

Answer (score 0):

I lately got the error! The image I wanted to refer is under a parent of Relative Layout without ImageView. When I add the jpg image under ImageView background and removing the image from Relative Layout's background image, the uriToImage reference finally works!